# Add a label next to entry widget Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label

I am trying to add a label next to each entry widget in my Tkinter GUI, but when doing so, I am getting an error saying `global name Label not defined`.

This is my code so far:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

class SampleApp(Tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.can_fname = Tk.Entry(self)
        self.can_lname = Tk.Entry(self)
        self.cl_fname = Tk.Entry(self)
        self.cl_lname = Tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = Tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.can_fname.pack()
        self.can_lname.pack()
        self.cl_fname.pack()
        self.cl_lname.pack()

    def on_button(self):
       a=self.can_fname.get()
       b='hello %s' %(a)
       with open('filename.txt', 'w') as myfile:
          myfile.write(b)

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You say you get "Label not defined" but nowhere in your code do you call `Label`. Here's a hint: look at how you create buttons; you need to use the same calling convention for the label widget.

Comment: Add `self.labelX = Tk.Label(self, ...)` followed by a  `self.labelX.pack()` call for each one desired before the corresponding `Tk.Entry()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the grid manager. Use the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="My Label")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        ## Do not pack() if you grid():
        # self.label.pack()
        # self.entry.pack()
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is taking up the other answer, only that it is checked with the code in question, tested and working.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.can_fname_label = tk.Label(self, text="can_fname_label")
        self.can_fname = tk.Entry(self)
        self.can_lname_label = tk.Label(self, text="can_lname_label")        
        self.can_lname = tk.Entry(self)
        self.cl_fname_label = tk.Label(self, text="cl_fname_label")        
        self.cl_fname = tk.Entry(self)
        self.cl_lname_label = tk.Label(self, text="cl_lname_label")        
        self.cl_lname = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.can_fname_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.can_fname.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')
        self.can_lname_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.can_lname.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
        self.cl_fname_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.cl_fname.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')
        self.cl_lname_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.cl_lname.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')
        self.button.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='w')

    def on_button(self):
       a=self.can_fname.get()
       b='hello %s' %(a)
       with open('filename.txt', 'w') as myfile:
          myfile.write(b)

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Makes:

[image]

And the click on the button saves a file in the folder of the python file:

[image]